# write code within a div instead of body with documentwrite

Tags: jquery

I would like to document.write this code but within a div:

```
 document.write('<img class="leaves'+i+'" src="'+rndLeaf+'" style="background-color:none;position:absolute;top:'+Ypos[i]+'px;left:'+Xpos[i]+'px;height:'+height[i]+'px;width:'+width[i]+'px;opacity:'+opacityLeaf[i]+';">');
```

At the moment this code writes it within the body element.

is this possible?

Comment: is it on the same asp page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$("div").append('<img class="leaves'+i+'" src="'+rndLeaf+'" style="background-color:none;position:absolute;top:'+Ypos[i]+'px;left:'+Xpos[i]+'px;height:'+height[i]+'px;width:'+width[i]+'px;opacity:'+opacityLeaf[i]+';">');
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have tagged it with JQuery then you can use the [append() function](https://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
var html = '<img class="leaves'+i+'" src="'+rndLeaf+'" style="background-color:none;position:absolute;top:'+Ypos[i]+'px;left:'+Xpos[i]+'px;height:'+height[i]+'px;width:'+width[i]+'px;opacity:'+opacityLeaf[i]+';">';

$("div").append(html);
```

If you want a specific `div`, say based an an `id` value of `"myDiv"`, then try this:

```
$("#myDiv").append(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you wish to use jQuery, use it: `$('#idOfDiv').html('Your text string');`

Comment: using `html()` will cause a replace, and it looks like the OP might be doing this is a loop, so you would want to use `append()` instead, as to avoid only have the last loop displayed. This would be more comparable to `document.write`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)**

```
$('#yourDivId').append('<img class="leaves'+i+'" src="'+rndLeaf+'" style="background-color:none;position:absolute;top:'+Ypos[i]+'px;left:'+Xpos[i]+'px;height:'+height[i]+'px;width:'+width[i]+'px;opacity:'+opacityLeaf[i]+';">');
```

or pure JS using:

```
var yourDiv = document.getElementById("your_div_id");
yourDiv.innerHTML += '<img class="leaves'+i+'" src="'+rndLeaf+'" style="background-color:none;position:absolute;top:'+Ypos[i]+'px;left:'+Xpos[i]+'px;height:'+height[i]+'px;width:'+width[i]+'px;opacity:'+opacityLeaf[i]+';">';
```